# How to delete all folders except latest 3 folders in efficient way in unix

Tags: unix, ksh

```
-rw-r--r--    1 SUPER.SUPER        SUPER      48615 May 30 11:47 do.jck8b
-rw-r--r--    1 SUPER.SUPER        SUPER      48629 May 30 11:47 do.jck8b.64
drwxrwxrwx    1 SUPER.SUPER        SUPER       4096 May 30 12:16 2018-05-28
drwxrwxrwx    1 SUPER.SUPER        SUPER       4096 May 30 14:28 J22
drwxrwxrwx    1 SUPER.SUPER        SUPER       4096 Jun  4 15:54 2018-05-29
drwxrwxrwx    1 SUPER.SUPER        SUPER       4096 Jun  4 15:54 2018-05-23
drwxrwxrwx    1 SUPER.SUPER        SUPER       4096 Jun  4 21:26 2018-05-22
```

My requirement is delete all the folders except latest 3 folders,
Sample output is:

```
2018-05-29
2018-05-23
2018-05-22
```

I tried this way but it takes lots of time to delete , is ther any alterbative way to do this...

```
find . -name "*" | grep -v 2018-05-29 | grep -v 2018-05-23 | grep -v 2018-05-22 | grep -v do.jck | xargs rm -rf
```

Comment: try this: `ls -lrt |grep ^d |head -n -3 |xargs rmdir`

Answer (score 0):

#### By last modified time

```
# Starting with these directory contents
$ ls -l
total 24
drwxr-xr-x 2 chuckx chuckx 4096 Jun  5 08:27 2018-05-25
drwxr-xr-x 2 chuckx chuckx 4096 Jun  5 08:26 2018-05-26
drwxr-xr-x 2 chuckx chuckx 4096 Jun  4 23:29 2018-05-27
drwxr-xr-x 2 chuckx chuckx 4096 Jun  4 23:29 2018-05-28
drwxr-xr-x 2 chuckx chuckx 4096 Jun  4 23:29 2018-05-29
-rw-r--r-- 1 chuckx chuckx   98 Jun  4 23:29 mkdirs.sh

# List only directories and sort by reversed modified time
$ ls -dlrt */
drwxr-xr-x 2 chuckx chuckx 4096 Jun  4 23:29 2018-05-29/
drwxr-xr-x 2 chuckx chuckx 4096 Jun  4 23:29 2018-05-28/
drwxr-xr-x 2 chuckx chuckx 4096 Jun  4 23:29 2018-05-27/
drwxr-xr-x 2 chuckx chuckx 4096 Jun  5 08:26 2018-05-26/
drwxr-xr-x 2 chuckx chuckx 4096 Jun  5 08:27 2018-05-25/

# Removed the detailed listing to just get filenames
$ ls -drt */
2018-05-29/  2018-05-28/  2018-05-27/  2018-05-26/  2018-05-25/

# Strip the last three lines (i.e. the most recent directories)
$ ls -drt */ | head -n -3
2018-05-29/
2018-05-28/

# Pipe the results to xargs to execute rmdir
$ ls -drt */ | head -n -3 | xargs rmdir

# Look at the results
$ ls
2018-05-25  2018-05-26  2018-05-27  mkdirs.sh
```

#### By date embedded in filename

```
# Starting with these directory contents
$ ls
2018-05-25  2018-05-26  2018-05-27  2018-05-28  2018-05-29  mkdirs.sh

# List only the directories
$ ls -d */
2018-05-25/  2018-05-26/  2018-05-27/  2018-05-28/  2018-05-29/

# Pipe to sort, just to be certain
$ ls -d */ | sort
2018-05-25/
2018-05-26/
2018-05-27/
2018-05-28/
2018-05-29/

# Strip the last three lines (i.e. most recent directories)
$ ls -d */ | sort | head -n -3
2018-05-25/
2018-05-26/

# Pipe the results to xargs to execute rmdir
$ ls -d */ | sort | head -n -3 | xargs rmdir

# Look at the results
$ ls
2018-05-27  2018-05-28  2018-05-29  mkdirs.sh
```